# Internal link scroll does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 internal links that DOES work, however, I also have 2 "To Top" links that doesn't work. They stopped working ever since I erased my nav and instead added the bootstrap nav. But I can't see why the bootstrap nav shouldn't be able to handle the same thing.

```js
var main = function() {



$(window).scroll(function(){
 $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
  $(".dropdown img").removeClass("rotate");
 });



//Internal link smooth scrolling

$("#topper").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop:0
  },"slow");
});

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;
      var $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });


};



$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
/*body*/
html, body {
 font-size: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}

/*nav*/
.navbar {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: solid #6ed3cf 2px;
 margin: 0;

 /*Kun on scroll!!!
 -moz-box-shadow:    0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    box-shadow:         0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    */
}


.navbar p {
 color: black;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
 border-bottom: solid transparent 2px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
 color: #6ed3cf;
}

/*
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active {
 color: #6ed3cf;
}
*/

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background: black;
 -webkit-transition: width .8s, height .8s, -webkit-transform .8s; /* Safari */
    transition: width .8s, height .8s, transform .8s;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 border: none;
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:visited {
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 width: 22px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }

  .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
   transform: rotate(0);
  }

   .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

/*Header*/
.header {
 /*/Users/jonashansen/Desktop/hjemmeside/img*/
 background: url(/img/arg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(60, 195, 191, 0.7);
 min-height: 100%;
 display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

#rowheader h1 {
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 3em;
}

#rowheader h2 {
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
}
/*
#rowheader h1 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 3em;


}
*/

/*Section1*/
#section1 {
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 3em;
 margin-bottom: 3em; 
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}

#section1 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
 display: block;
}

#section1 h3 {
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section1 p {
 line-height: 2em;
 padding: 1em 0 0;
}

#section1 a {
 color: #3DD0AC;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#section1 a:hover {
 color: black;
}

/*Section2*/
#section2 {
 line-height: 1.8em;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
 position: relative;
}

#section2 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 2.5em 1em;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}

#section2 h3 {
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section2 p {
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 padding-bottom: 2em; 
}

#section2 a {
 color: #3DD0AC;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#section2 img {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#img-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#img-wrapper img {
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

#img-wrapper img:hover {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.1);
}

/*Section3*/
#section3 {
 height: 50%;
 background: #6ed3cf;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 height: 20em;
}

#section3 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section3 i {
 padding: 0.5em;
 color: black;
}

/*Footer*/
#footer {
 background:#fff;
 color: black;
 height: 6%;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

#footer a {
 font-size: 0.8em;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: none;
   padding-top: 1.2em;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 500;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {


 .logo p {
 font-size: 60%;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-top: 0.4em;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 }

 .header {
 background:url(/img/arg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(60, 195, 191, 0.7);
 min-height: 100%
 }

 #rowheader {
 margin-top: 3em;
 }

 #rowheader h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
 }

 #section1 p {
 padding: 0 2em;
 }

 #footer {
  height:25%;
 }

 #footer a {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: table-cell;
   padding-top: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 0.9em;
 }

 #footer p {
 display: table-row;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="topper" href="#"><p>&lt;&frasl;BY&#95;SUONPERA&gt;</p></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#My_Work">My Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
 <div class="header">
  <div class="container" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
   <div id="rowheader">
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <h2>blablablablar</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Section1 -->
 <div id="section1" class="container">
  <h2 id="About">About</h2>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h3>Me</h3>
    <p>blablablablabla</p><br><br> 
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>



<!-- Section2 -->
 <div  id="section2" class="container">
  <h2 id="My_Work">My Work</h2>
 </div>

<!-- Section3 --> 
 <div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <div>
   <h2 id="Contact">Want to get in touch?</h2> 
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <p>blablablabla</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a>  
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


<!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
  <a id="topper" href="#">BACK TO TOP</a>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some part of your code seems to be missing, like `<nav>` opening tag. Also a `<div>` opening tag there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `event` parameter from `$("#topper").click(function(){`:

```
$("#topper").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop:0
  },"slow");
});
```

Also add the `on` click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#topper", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('id');
  var $target = $("#" + target);
  console.log($target);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 'slow');
});
```

See updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6bsqwp4u/7/).

Comment: This definitely does make one of the non-working links work. But it stops the other links from working

Comment: @suonpera, I've changed the code a bit. That should work. See my updated answer. I've also added a working fiddle.

Comment: The back to top is working. But the nav is no longer fixed. Could that be the reason why? That the nav simply can't be fixed?

Comment: @suonpera What? I don't understand. It's not fixed because you didn't make it fixed. I don't see any code to suggest that you tried making it to stay fixed.

Comment: Running your fiddle, the the links DOES work. But the navbar is not fixed, which I need it to be. So I'm wondering, maybe it wouldn't work if the navbar is fixed?

Comment: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6bsqwp4u/2/. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes now it is fixed. But the 'to top' link does not work

Comment: @suonpera, see the update answer with working fiddle.

Comment: Almost! Everything works now, except that the links: 'about', 'my work' and contact, do not perform a 'smooth scroll' like before. They simply jump to the anchor

Comment: @suonpera, Check now. Just updated the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks for using your time on this @Ionut! Everything works like a charm..

Comment: @suonpera Awesome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the word `navtop` near `#` in `<a id="navtop" href="#topper">BACK TO TOP</a>`  and add id in nav bar

```js
var main = function() {



  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
    $(".dropdown img").removeClass("rotate");
  });



  //Internal link smooth scrolling

  $("#topper").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
  });

  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });


};



$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
/*body*/

html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
/*nav*/

.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid #6ed3cf 2px;
  margin: 0;
  /*Kun on scroll!!!
 -moz-box-shadow:    0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    box-shadow:         0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    */
}
.navbar p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
  border-bottom: solid transparent 2px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #6ed3cf;
}
/*
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active {
 color: #6ed3cf;
}
*/

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: black;
  -webkit-transition: width .8s, height .8s, -webkit-transform .8s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width .8s, height .8s, transform .8s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:visited {
  background: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
/*Header*/

.header {
  /*/Users/jonashansen/Desktop/hjemmeside/img*/
  background: url(/img/arg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(60, 195, 191, 0.7);
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#rowheader h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}
#rowheader h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}
/*
#rowheader h1 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 3em;


}
*/

/*Section1*/

#section1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#section1 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
  display: block;
}
#section1 h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}
#section1 p {
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
}
#section1 a {
  color: #3DD0AC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#section1 a:hover {
  color: black;
}
/*Section2*/

#section2 {
  line-height: 1.8em;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
#section2 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
#section2 h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}
#section2 p {
  padding: 0 0 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
#section2 a {
  color: #3DD0AC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#section2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img-wrapper img {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
#img-wrapper img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
/*Section3*/

#section3 {
  height: 50%;
  background: #6ed3cf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0.5em;
  height: 20em;
}
#section3 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#section3 i {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: black;
}
/*Footer*/

#footer {
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#footer a {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo p {
    font-size: 60%;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  }
  .header {
    background: url(/img/arg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(60, 195, 191, 0.7);
    min-height: 100%
  }
  #rowheader {
    margin-top: 3em;
  }
  #rowheader h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  #section1 p {
    padding: 0 2em;
  }
  #footer {
    height: 25%;
  }
  #footer a {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  #footer p {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navtop">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="topper" href="#">
        <p>&lt;&frasl;BY&#95;SUONPERA&gt;</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#My_Work">My Work</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="container" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <div id="rowheader">
      <h1>HI</h1>
      <h2>blablablablar</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Section1 -->
<div id="section1" class="container">
  <h2 id="About">About</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h3>Me</h3>
      <p>blablablablabla</p>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Section2 -->
<div id="section2" class="container">
  <h2 id="My_Work">My Work</h2>
</div>

<!-- Section3 -->
<div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <div>
    <h2 id="Contact">Want to get in touch?</h2> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <p>blablablabla</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
  <a id="topper" href="#navtop">BACK TO TOP</a>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2016</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works! But it does not work if the navbar is fixed to the top. Any solution to this?

Comment: you need to set id for a nav bar and call the id in href

Comment: If you have a fixed nav bar then you need to set id to movable object at top and call that id